# Taking the difference between a string (JSON formatted) date and a swift date

Tags: javascript, json, swift, date, datetime

I have a problem in swift that I can't quite get my head around because I don't fully understand the swift Date() object.

I have a string stored in a variable formatted like such:
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

For example, the date string might be "2014-08-21T19:32:00Z"

I want to take the difference between that datetime and the current datetime in swift. I know you can format swift dates similarly using the DateFormatter object, but how do I get the offset between the two? Ideally the difference would be returned in such a way that I could extract the days, hours, minutes, etc.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string date to a swift date and then you can compare.

I had this same task where the date may or may not be in the JSON result, so I wrote this handy little function to get the date (change the date format as needed - I had two possible formats):

```
func getDateFromString(_ dateString: String?) -> Date? {
    guard let dateString = dateString else {
        return nil
    }
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
    var date: Date?
    date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    if date == nil {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"
        date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    }
    return date   
}
```

Then you need to play with the calendar and calendar components.

```
let now = Date()
if let stringDate = getDateFromString("2014-08-21T19:32:00Z") {
let calendar = Calendar.current
let comparison = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute], from: stringDate, to: now)

print("The Difference between the dates is: \(comparison.day!) days, \(comparison.hour!) hours, and \(comparison.minute!) minutes.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must convert the string into a `Date` using a date formatter configured with the correct ISO 8601 format string. If you're targeting iOS 10 or later, you can use the very convenient `ISO8601DateFormatter` instead.

Once you have 2 date objects, it's easy to figure out the difference between the 2. If you'd like to turn that difference back into something readable, I'd suggest either `DateIntervalFormatter` or `DateComponentsFormatter`, depending on your use case. I've included 2 different ways to access the years, weeks, day, etc.

```
let dateString = "2014-08-21T19:32:00Z"

// iOS 10 or later
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

// Older deployment targets
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"


if let jsonDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {

    let today = Date()

    // Number of seconds between the 2
    let difference = today.timeIntervalSince(jsonDate)

    let componentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    componentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .short
    componentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond]
    let string = componentsFormatter.string(from: jsonDate, to: today)
    print(string!)


    let comparison = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second, .nanosecond], from: jsonDate, to: today)

    print(comparison)
}
```

Output:

> 2 yrs, 11 mths, 20 days, 4 hr, 41 min, 32 sec
>   year: 2 month: 11 day: 20 hour: 4 minute: 41 second: 32 nanosecond: 864941162 isLeapMonth: false